# Can't resolve module in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx, webpack-2

According to the following: Webpack 2: [cannot resolve module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39933782/418343)

I have tried to use `modules` instead of `alias` to load my component like this :

```
  resolve: {
    modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules',path.resolve('./app/components')],
    alias:{
      applicationStyles:'app/styles/app.scss'
    },
```

but i get the following webpack error:

> ERROR in ./app/app.jsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'TodoApp' in 'C:....'  @ ./app/app.jsx 10:14-32  @ multi
>   babel-polyfill script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
>   script-loader!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js ./app/app.jsx

---

Every thing goes okay, If i use `alias` for each component instead like this:

```
 resolve: {
    modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules'],
    alias:{
      applicationStyles:'app/styles/app.scss',
      TodoApp: 'app/components/TodoApp.jsx'
    },
    extensions: ['*','.js','.jsx;']
  },
```

Comment: The error you wrote says that it can't resolve module `TodoApp`. It says nothing about `applicationStyles`. You must be importing `TodoApp` somewhere.

Comment: @LukeVella: yes the error related to the configuration of `TodoApp` component in webpack, because when i use the `alias` section instead of `modules` section, every thing goes okay.

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare could you prepare some repo with that problem?

Comment: Could you make some snippet or gist with importing code example?  
You should import your custom components which are not in `node_modules` by relative path (`from '../components/Todo'`)

Comment: @Tomasz https://github.com/MohammedNagar/react-todo

Comment: @LukeVella https://github.com/MohammedNagar/react-todo

Comment: is that a rogue `;` in `extensions` should be `extensions: ['*','.js','.jsx']` ?

Comment: I cloned the repository and changed the webpack config to use modules for the components directory exactly as you wrote it and it works fine for me. Try deleting your node_modules directory and reinstalling your dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `semicolon` in `resolve.extensions` property: `'.jsx;'`.
This semicolon was the root of the problem why `resolve.modules` didn't work.

When you remove this semicolon and add `'app/components'` to `resolve.modules`, webpack bundles without errors.

**webpack.config.js** *(after changes)*

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    'script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script-loader!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js',
    './app/app.jsx',
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js',
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [__dirname, 'app/components', 'node_modules'],
    alias: {
      applicationStyles: 'app/styles/app.scss',
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'es2017', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
        },
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: ['./node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot, is there away to debug config file, to detect stupid syntax errors like this?! the error message is misleading.

Comment: webpack 2.x and 3.x has validation of provided config built in. Packages like https://github.com/js-dxtools/webpack-validator are deprecated in favour of using "just webpack", see also https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2971